# I'd like to know the name of this aircraft

Tags: aircraft-identification, fighter, wwii

I recognize it but can't recall the name, if anyone can tell me that would be great.

[image: Aircraft]

Comment: Well I MUS say, DANG, I just can't recall what airplane that is--

Comment: Google "American WW2 fighters" or something like that and you'll soon know the answer--

Comment: @quiet flyer, this is the very definition of low hanging fruit!  Someone will answer this.  And score a few points...  ;)

Comment: P.S.  @warwizard57, sorry to tease, but your handle doesn't match the question.  Because if you truly were a war wizard you would know that this is only the most ubiquitous and popular fighter of its era.  Instantantly recognizable by most aviation buffs, it has since dominated air racing, and been reproduced in many smaller scale home built aircraft.

Comment: sorry just realized the pun after some thought, my specialty is ground armor in WWII, I don't do well in the aviation department

Comment: Is it perhaps specifically one owned by the CAF?

Comment: Most postwar Mustangs are "Cavaliers", a postwar civilian retrofit of surplus Mustangs for sale to the sport pilot market in the late 40s/early 50s.  This is why there are so many of them compared to other warbirds where almost all went directly to the scrap yard.  Cavaliers included a back seat in place of the radios and fuel tank in addition to stripping out the weapons, armour and armament.  Because of the back seat, the canopy has a bulge to the rear giving them a bit of a squared off look, whereas stock Mustang canopies were a pure teardrop shape.

Comment: I was going to suggest that a Google Image Search would solve the problem, but when I tried it it identified this P-51 as a P-47!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a P-51D Mustang. The main clue for the "D" model is the bubble canopy.

To identify it as a P-51:

It has D-day paint stripes, which means it is not an obscure prototype of some other American fighter design.

It has a belly-mounted cooling air scoop, square rudder, wingtip and elevator tip profiles, and an induction air inlet under the prop spinner- which all distinguish it from the P-40, along with the bubble canopy.

It has a 4-blade prop, which distinguishes it from the P-39.

It has the engine in the nose and no cannon firing through the prop spinner, which distinguish it from the P-39 and the P-63.

Comment: … not only probably, but certainly!

Comment: It would be great to improve this answer with the detail which identifies it as a D model (And a P-51 in general)

Comment: @Jamiec, will edit. -NN